# SiteMapPath Disappears on sub page

Tags: asp.net, sitemap, sitemappath

For some reason on my page my SiteMapPath disappears.

Site structure:

```
WebApp
-Default.aspx
-> Reports\
----Default.aspx
----MyReport.aspx
```

Web.sitemap

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >
  <siteMapNode url="~/Default.aspx" title="Overview"  description="Overview">
    <siteMapNode url="~/Reports/Default.aspx" title="Reports"  description="Reports" >
      <siteMapNode url="~/Reports/MyReport.aspx" title="MyReport"  description="MyReport" />
    </siteMapNode>
  </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

The SiteMapPath will display when I'm on the overview page of the reports page but not the MyReport page. With the sitemap bound to a treeview I see all of my nodes correctly.

Works - shows me on MyReport Page

```
<asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="Server" DataSourceID="SitePathDataSource">
</asp:TreeView>
```

Disappears on MyReport Page but visible on all others

```
<asp:SiteMapPath ID="SiteMapPath1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SitePathDataSource">
</asp:SiteMapPath>
```

Comment: What type of control are you using to display the sitemap.  you said a treeview works correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly an expert on this.  I did just test it on my pages and it worked fine.  The only difference between what I am doing and yours is I am not specifying a filename on the parent node.  Although I kind of stumbled into that one because I couldn't have the same path twice in my sitemap.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >  
    <siteMapNode url="~/Default.aspx" title="Overview"  description="Overview">   
        <siteMapNode url="~/Reports/" title="Reports"  description="Reports" >      
            <siteMapNode url="~/Reports/Default.aspx" title="Reports Home"  description="Home" />
            <siteMapNode url="~/Reports/MyReport.aspx" title="MyReport"  description="MyReport" />    
        </siteMapNode>  
    </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

Comment: This issue is I don't want Reports and MyReport on the same level, I want MyReport to show UNDER Report. I tried switching my sitemap structure to yours to see what happened differently once again it shows the structure as expected in the treeview but the sitemappath still doesn't display.

Comment: Whats your SiteMap DataSource look like.  Try removing the DataSourceID all together from the SiteMapPath control. Its not required if you are using a root web.sitemap file.

Answer (score 0):

What is the URL in your browser when the control is not displayed?  I'd bet that you have a querystring value or something that does not match Reports/Myreport.aspx.  If the path of the page does not match an item exactly in the sitemapnode it won't display.

Answer (score 0):

Assign sitemap provider in page_load of page

```
SiteMapPath1.SiteMapProvider = "DefaultSiteMap"
```

inside web.config

```
    <siteMap defaultProvider="DefaultSiteMap" enabled="true">
<providers>
<add name="DefaultSiteMap" type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" siteMapFile="~\SiteMaps
\Default.sitemap" />
</providers>
```